# CSS Subgrid not keeping same with and height across parent Grid columns

Tags: html, css

I am struggling making the following code working.

I need to create a layout that contains 4 columns and each column contains a first  with a fixed height of 30px, followed by a  that wrap a grid of 4 divs (positioned in 2 rows and 2 columns), that must have the same with and height across the 4 parent columns.

I am sure I am using some CSS Subgrid wrong but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto;
  gap: 5px;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.subgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 1</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
      <div class="box">ads</div>
      <div class="box">ad</div>
      <div class="box">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 2</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 3</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 4</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
      <div class="box">asd</div>
      <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Maximus dolor, inquit, brevis est. Nescio quo modo praetervolavit oratio. Quis hoc dicit? Summus dolor s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `width` and `height` of all `.subgrid` children to be equal, you have to use `repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))` for both `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` but you have to be aware because the text may overlap with the `.box` when using `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))` so you might leave it as `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)` or to handle that situations by another way.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto;
  gap: 5px;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.subgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 1</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
      <div class="box">ads</div>
      <div class="box">ad</div>
      <div class="box">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 2</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 3</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">Header 4</div>
    <div class="subgrid">
      <div class="box">asd</div>
      <div class="box">asd</div>
      <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Maximus dolor, inquit, brevis est. Nescio quo modo praetervolavit oratio. Quis hoc dicit? Summus dolor s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```